# How to Drag and Drop a Value from a UITableView Cell to another UITableView Cell in iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I have two UITableView in my iPhone application and my task is to Drag first UITableView Selected Value into second UITableView.

It is possible or not ?

If is is not possible then please provide me the way to Drag and Drop Value from one control to another control.

Please provide me answer as early as possible

Thanks in advance.